# What is the formula for the force of friction as a vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, vectors, definition

The formula I've grown up with is $F_{fr} = \mu F_{N}$, where

- $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction between the object and the surface
- $F_{N}$ is the normal force of the surface acting upon the object
- $F_{fr}$ is the force of friction between the object and the surface

Treating them strictly as vectors, this formula above seems impossible to take literally, since it would imply that $F_{fr}$ and $F_{N}$ are parallel.  But in fact if you draw a free-body diagram, they ought to be orthogonal.

**EDIT:**

OK, so if this formula above is only for computing magnitude, then treating these forces as vectors, it seems correct to write

$\|F_{fr}\| = \mu\|F_{N}\|$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ represents the norm function)

and if we pair this with the understanding that the force of friction has the opposite direction as that of the accelerating force, this would seem to give a complete definition/formula for computing $F_{fr}$.

Is this the only way to think the force of friction?  Or can it be defined more concisely using some vector equation instead?

Comment: The friction force is always against the movement , i.e. against the acceleration, Your formula gives its magnitude, so you can not "Treating them strictly as vectors"

Comment: I am completely aware of that, which is why $F_{fr}$ and $F_{N}$ are orthogonal, and hence the equation above cannot be true in the vector sense.  My question is, what is the vector analogue of the equation I gave (which, as you say, can only be used to calculate the magnitude of the force of friction).  Or are you saying that no such formula exists?

Comment: You are right and I told you so. Nobody claims that it is a vector equation.

Comment: OK thank you.  I have edited my question to reflect what you have pointed out.  But the question is still unanswered.

Comment: @trula The friction force is *not* always against the movement, and it's also no always against the acceleration (which are two different things!).  The friction force opposes *sliding*, but friction can both cause things to slow down *or* speed up, and friction can ask in the direction of motion or opposite the direction of motion.  All that matters is that friction *opposes the sliding*.

Comment: I use this equation $\overrightarrow{F}=-\mu \left| F_{N}\right| sign\left( v_{t}\right) \cdot \widehat{t}$ where $v_t$ is the tangential velocity at the contact point and t is the tangent at the contact point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is clear and the answer is also clear: no, there is no **vector** equation.

The only equation that makes sense is on the moduli, as you have written.

The forces **are** indeed orthogonal, as you pointed out. The friction force can only be parallel to the contact surface.

And whatever the direction of the **total force** $F$ **applied** on the object, only the **normal component** $F_N$ enters your equation, and being **normal** to the surface, this force is indeed orthogonal to the friction force.

Of course the friction force need not be orthogonal to the **total** force. On a slope, weight is vertical, but the is friction **not** horizontal. Friction is along the slope, proportional to the **normal** component of the weight, orthogonal to the slope.

Comment: Thanks Alfred.  As for there being no vector equation, can you take a look at the one I suggested in the answer I posted?  I think it works since its takes into account being in the opposite direction as the accelerating force, and also guarantees that the norm will come out to be $\mu$ times the norm of $F_{N}$.

Comment: When I said the forces are not orthogonal I means in the sense that it does not contradict the friction equation, i.e., I meant that $\vec f_{f}\ne \mu\vec F_N$. I will clarify since it appears you downvoted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I model the situation.

Typically, there are two cases in the frame of the surface:

- If there is no sliding between surfaces, with the system in static equilibrium,
  then we have static friction and "$\vec F_f$  is whatever it needs to be to satisfy Newton's Law":

  $$\vec 0 \stackrel{eqbm}{=} { \require{cancel} m {\cancelto{\vec 0}{\!\!\vec a}}}=\vec F_{net} \equiv \vec F_{f} + \sum_{i\neq f} \vec F_i.$$

  Thus, in this case, $$\vec F_{f} \stackrel{eqbm}{=} - \sum_{i\neq f} \vec F_i.$$
  In particular, it need not be as large as $\mu_s N$...it could be less (even zero) if Newton's Law requires it.

  (We certainly don't want $F_f=\mu_s F_N$ if it were to violate the static equilibrium condition.)

  In general, what is true about static friction is that:
  whatever its magnitude is, it's no greater than $\mu_s F_N$: that is,
  $F_{f,s} \not\gt \mu_s N$.

  *(Soapbox: I think writing $F_{f,s} \leq \mu_s F_N$ invites students to mistakenly "choose" $\mu_s F_N$ since that symbol suggests "it could be $\mu_sF_N$". My "not greater than" symbol says "what it can't be"... look elsewhere [Newton's Laws] for what it is.)*
- If there is sliding between surfaces (so  $v_{rel}>0$), then
  the kinetic friction opposes the sliding:
  $$\vec F_f = -\hat v_{rel} (\mu_k F_N),$$
  where $F_N$ is the magnitude of the normal force.

Comment: What does the strikethrough through the acceleration mean?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I somehow want to say (using what I know about MathJax) that the acceleration is zero. (I tried an edit.)

Comment: Oh right. I think it's quite clear without any additional typesetting but if you want extra clarification you could use  \underbrace or \cancelto

Answer (score 0):

> Treating them strictly as vectors, this formula above seems impossible
> to take literally, since it would imply that $F_{fr}$ and $F_{N}$ are
> parallel.  But in fact if you draw a free-body diagram, they ought to
> be orthogonal.

The fact that the forces are orthogonal does not mean the friction force and normal force vectors are related by the friction equation by

$$\vec f_{f}= \mu\vec F_N$$

The equation

$$f_{f}=\mu F_N$$

Relates the *magnitude* of the friction force to the *magnitude* of the normal force. It is not a vector equation. The friction force vector always acts parallel to and in opposition to some applied force vector. That would be a vector equation.

> It seems that $F_{fr} = -\mu\frac{\|F_{N}\|}{\|F_{a}\|}F_{a}$ does the
> job.

I'm not quite sure why you using the ratio of the magnitude of the normal force to applied force, but I don't believe it "does the job" for a few reasons.

First of all you have to consider the two types of friction: Static and kinetic.

Let's start with static friction.

In the case of static friction, the normal force is only applicable when the applied force equals the maximum possible static friction force which is $\mu_{s}F_N$. Up to that point the static friction force is a variable that always matches the applied force and *is independent of the normal force* so that the object involved is in equilibrium. That is

$$\vec F_{fr}=-\vec F_a$$

when

$$F_{a}\lt\mu_{s}F_N$$

Now regarding kinetic friction.

When the maximum possible static friction force is reached, friction transitions to kinetic friction (generally lower than static). The magnitude of the kinetic friction is

$$F_{fr}=\mu_{k}F_N$$

The kinetic friction opposes the applied force, *but unlike static friction, it is generally considered independent of magnitude of the applied force and the velocity.*

Consequently, I don't see how your equation applies to kinetic friction since the kinetic friction force $F_{fr}$ is independent of $F_a$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this has already been stated in my question, which I guess was not clear.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to make it more clear.

Comment: @doggo I posted my answer before seeing your edit.

Comment: my apologies then!

Comment: @doggo Did you downvote my answer?

Comment: No but I did not upvote it either.

Comment: @doggo There was no upvote. But your new "answer" does not do the job. I will explain.

Comment: @BobD  **I** downvoted your answer, because you wrote "No it does not mean the forces are orthogonal" but they are !

Comment: @BobD I just "de-downvoted" your edited answer. I have also removed my negative remark about your answer in mine.

Comment: @doggo See update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $\mathbf{F_{fr}} = -\mu\frac{\|\mathbf{F_{N}}\|}{\|\mathbf{F_{a}}\|}\mathbf{F_{a}}$ does the job,
where $\mathbf{F_{a}}$ is the accelerating force acting in an opposite direction to $\mathbf{F_{fr}}$.

Comment: No, sorry, because it is not at all clear what $F_a$ is. Your equation is , at best,   a definition of $F_a$ ! But not even, as it is a tautological definition. If you think about it, **any** vector parallel to the friction force and of opposite direction fits this equation... ;)

Comment: If there is no accelerating force, can there still be a force of friction?

Comment: The point is, there must be **some** force. But the force can have **any direction** and only the normal component determines the friction. What do you call the "accelerating force" ?

Comment: I see your point!  My question was phrased very generally, yet I am imagining a very specific scenario which I should have specified in my original question.